# How to change a existing search query on rails app after implementing friendly_id slug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

I have a existing method to query on certain Models, where they are querying based on `category_id` and `sub_category`. On the landing page it used to generate url like this `localhost:3000/search?category_id=208`and it used to contain the result based on that category. And now that I implemented `friendly_id` gem I am able to generate the url as follows `localhost:3000/search?category_id=metal-processing-machine-tool`. But looks like this affected the existing search functionality because although it is displaying the right url based on the category_id selected it is not displaying the results at all. Other words querying is not happening.

Following is my existing search functionality:
**search**

```
def search_equipments
    begin
      if (params.keys & ['category_id', 'sub_category', 'manufacturer', 'country', 'state', 'keyword']).present?
        if params[:category_id].present?
          @category = Category.active.find params[:category_id]
        else
          @category = Category.active.find params[:sub_category] if params[:sub_category].present?
        end
        @root_categories = Category.active.roots
        @sub_categories = @category.children.active if params[:category_id].present?
        @sub_categories ||= {}
        @countries = Country.active.all
        @manufacturers = Manufacturer.active.all
        @states = State.active.where("country_id = ?", params[:country]) if params[:country].present?
        @states ||= {}
        @equipments = Equipment.active.filter(params.slice(:manufacturer, :country, :state, :category_id, :sub_category, :keyword))
      else
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Something went wrong!"
    end
  end
```

This is how I am generating the url currently.

```
<%= search_equipments_path(:category_id => category.slug ) %>
```

This used to be like below. Instead of `category.slug` it was `category.id` and used query properly.

```
<%= search_equipments_path(:category_id => category.id ) %>
```

I am lost as I am not able to get the expected search result after implementing friendly_id. Can somebody please tell how can I fix this?

Updating with **category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]

  enum status: { inactive: 0, active: 1}
  acts_as_nested_set

  has_many :equipments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :subs_equipments, :foreign_key => "sub_category_id", :class_name => "Equipment"
  has_many :wanted_equipments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :services, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates_uniqueness_of  :name,message: "Category with this name already exists", scope: :parent_id
  scope :active, -> { where(status: 1) }

  def sub_categories
    Category.where(:parent_id=>self.id)
  end

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    true
  end

end
```

**categories** table

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",           limit: 255
    t.integer  "parent_id",      limit: 4
    t.integer  "status",         limit: 4,   default: 1
    t.integer  "lft",            limit: 4,               null: false
    t.integer  "rgt",            limit: 4,               null: false
    t.integer  "depth",          limit: 4,   default: 0, null: false
    t.integer  "children_count", limit: 4,   default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
    t.string   "slug",           limit: 255
  end
```

`Category.new` will give

`<Category id: nil, name: nil, parent_id: nil, status: 1, lft: nil, rgt: nil, depth: 0, children_count: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, slug: nil>`

Comment: Enums will create scopes by default. Therefore, `active` and `inactive` are already present. Remove your definition of `active`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from `@category = Category.active.find params[:category_id]`. `#find` expects id to be passed, however currently you are passing slug for `params[:category_id]`.

Try to use `Category.active.friendly.find params[:category_id]`. This will retrieve categories by slug.

This [article](http://olivierlacan.com/posts/migrating-an-ad-hoc-url-slug-system-to-friendly-id/) will help.

Comment: This `Category.active.friendly.find params[:category_id]`. Its still not querying.

Comment: Try `Category.active.find_by_slug params[:category_id]`. If this will hot help post your Category model.

Comment: That didnt work either @yzalavin. Posted extra information. Please check

Comment: If you have only added `friendly_id` only `params[:category_id]` should be affected. In your controller it affects `@category` definition and `Equipment.active.filter`. I suppose you have problem with a `@category`. Try manually `Category.active.friendly.find "metal-processing-machine-tool"` as in your example. If this will not help it is probably problem not in `friendly_id`.

Comment: Okay. I ran `Category.active.friendly.find "metal-processing-machine-tool"` on console. It gave me active record result of metal processing machine tool. So what should I do next?